# How to read all documents from collection in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Seems to be a simple question, but I can't find the answer. There is a collection of `posts`, documents of which have a field `rubric`. How to read ALL documents from this collection in mongoose using `Post.find ({rubric: value}, function)`, but keeping `rubric`. What `value` has to be for this to work?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGKD7HN-ka3) ?

Comment: @J.F., yes, thank you

Comment: @J.F., how many exists auxiliary words in mongodb and mongoose. Where can I read about this besides the official documentation?

Comment: Yes, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/). Also I'm going to answer the question in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find according if a field exists whatever value it has, you can use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in this way:

```
db.collection.find({
  "rubric": {
    "$exists": true
  }
})
```

Using mongoose is the same query. Something like this:

```
yourModel.find({
  "rubric": {
    "$exists": true
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGKD7HN-ka3).

Also, to know about these world in mongo world you can check [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) every time you have an issue.

At the left of the page you see "Reference > Operators" and there are a lof of different operators you can use.